# scanf_s not enough arguments passed for format string(Visual Studio)

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, scanf, tr24731

The program showing error as title.
What's wrong on scanf_s function?
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
    {
        struct Students
        {
            char name[10];
            int  snum;
            float  point;
        }st[5];

int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("-- Student Info --\n-");

    printf("Enter Your Name: ");
    scanf_s("%s",st[i].name);

    printf("\nEnter Your Number: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&st[i].snum);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%s` of [fscanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx) need buffer size. E.g `scanf_s("%s", st[i].name, sizeof(st[i].name));`

Comment: oh great it works,can u explain why i need add buffer size?

Comment: add the tag visual studio

Comment: To check that the input exceeds the buffer size. See the link of previous comment.

Comment: Did you read the documentation fro `scanf_s` and do you understand what makes it safe/secure?

Comment: thanks,I will check buffer size more detailed.

Comment: David Schwartz Visual Studio has special case such a use _s for security.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error usually comes when the compiler detects mismatch between number of arguments required to satisfy placeholders in format string and number of arguments supplied .

This was a new warning supplied in Visual Studio 2015 onwards  .
So for your code to work correctly you need to supply two arguments one is the address one and second one which is extra is the sizeof(variable) placeholder .

```
scanf_s("%s", &string, sizeof(string));
```

This would let the code work correctly .